# How to simplify these rooted square roots with Mathematica?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I mean

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[x + 2*Sqrt[2 x- 4]] - Sqrt[x-2*Sqrt[2 x-4]], Assumptions->x >= 2&&x<=4]
```

and

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[x + 2*Sqrt[2 x - 4]] - Sqrt[x - 2*Sqrt[2 x - 4]],Assumptions ->  x >= 4]
```

Both return the inputs, whereas

```
Plot[-Sqrt[x-2 Sqrt[-4+2 x]]+Sqrt[x+2 Sqrt[-4+2 x]],{x,-5,5},PlotTheme->Thick,PlotRange->All,AspectRatio->1]
```

[image]

shows `Piecewise[{{2*Sqrt[x-2],x>=2&&x<4},{2*Sqrt[2],x>=4}}]`.

Comment: With `Reduce[expr - y == 0 && x > 0 && y > 0, x]` you can get most of the way there, but I don't know how to get it to produce a nice Piecewise function straight away.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: `Reduce[Sqrt[x + 2*Sqrt[2 x - 4]] - Sqrt[x - 2*Sqrt[2 x - 4]] - y == 
   0 && x > 0 && y > 0, x]` performs `(0 < y < 2 Sqrt[2] && 
   x == 1/4 (8 + y^2)) || (y == 2 Sqrt[2] && (x > 4 || x == 4))`.

Comment: `Reduce[(0 < y < 2 Sqrt[2] && 
    x == 1/4 (8 + y^2)) || (y == 
     2 Sqrt[2] && (x > 4 || x == 4)), y, Reals]` results in `(2 < x <= 4 && y == Sqrt[-8 + 4 x]) || (x > 4 && y == 2 Sqrt[2])`, finishing the work. @SjoerdSmit, can you present your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, I suggested starting with

```
Reduce[Sqrt[x + 2*Sqrt[2 x - 4]] - Sqrt[x - 2*Sqrt[2 x - 4]] - y ==     0 && x > 0 && y > 0, x]
```

> (0 < y < 2 Sqrt[2] && x == 1/4 (8 + y^2)) || (y == 2 Sqrt[2] && (x > 4 || x == 4))

This can then be simplified to:

```
Reduce[%, y, Reals]
```

> (2 < x <= 4 && y == Sqrt[-8 + 4 x]) || (x > 4 && y == 2 Sqrt[2])